# Indexing an entity in an actor thread using Grails searchable

Tags: grails, compass-geolocation, searchable, grails-searchable, gpars

I am using the Grails searchable plugin to index an entity with a custom text representation. I want this entity to be indexed in an actor (using GPars) that will be triggered asynchronously once the entity was inserted. Is there any way to realize this using the searchable/compass framework with Grails?